# Implement row by row operation using ndarray

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust

I wanted to perform a loop operation that would do the following operation (operations must be element by element).

```
let mut spec = array![] // matrix mxn
let exponencial = array![] // 1xn

for k in 0..N {
    spectrum [k, ..] = spectrum [k, ..] * exponential;
}
```

How could I implement this operation correctly and efficiently? My intention is to implement it in a loop to compare with the implementation with other languages. Do I have to use some intermediate temporary array?

## Attempt 1

```rust
use ndarray::prelude::*; // 0.13.1

fn main() {
    // All rows in same time
    let mut spec = array![[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]; // mxn
    let exponencial = array![[1, 1, 1, 1]]; // matrix 1xn

    let _result = spec.assign(&(&spec * &exponencial));
    // or spec = &spec*&exponencial;

    //  In the form of a loop. one row each iteration.
    // This is the implementation that I want to make to be able
    // to implement it to be able to compare with other languages
    // 1)
    let mut spec = array![[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]; // mxn
    let exponencial = array![[1, 1, 1, 1]]; // matrix 1xn
    spec.slice_mut(s![0, ..])
        .assign(&(&(spec.row(0)) * &exponencial.row(0)));
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=54bcae36962b8a7c43dce81b88a34f3d)

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `spec` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:18:21
   |
17 |     spec.slice_mut(s![0, ..])
   |     ---- mutable borrow occurs here
18 |         .assign(&(&(spec.row(0)) * &exponencial.row(0)));
   |          ------     ^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
   |          |
   |          mutable borrow later used by call
```

## Attempt 2

```rust
use ndarray::prelude::*; // 0.13.1

fn main() {
    // All rows in same time
    let mut spec = array![[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]; // mxn
    let exponencial = array![[1, 1, 1, 1]]; // matrix 1xn

    let result = spec.assign(&(&spec * &exponencial));
    // or spec = &spec*&exponencial;

    //  In the form of a loop. one row each iteration.
    // This is the implementation that I want to make to be able
    // to implement it to be able to compare with other languages
    // 2)
    let mut spec = array![[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]; // mxn
    let exponencial = array![[1, 1, 1, 1]]; // matrix 1xn
    spec.row_mut(0) = &spec.row(0) * &exponencial.row(0);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bd85898099526c63e7ba0016679a7c68)

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:17:23
   |
17 |     spec.row_mut(0) = &spec.row(0) * &exponencial.row(0);
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `ndarray::ViewRepr`, found struct `ndarray::OwnedRepr`
   |
   = note: expected struct `ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::ViewRepr<&mut {integer}>, _>`
              found struct `ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<{integer}>, _>`

error[E0070]: invalid left-hand side of assignment
  --> src/main.rs:17:21
   |
17 |     spec.row_mut(0) = &spec.row(0) * &exponencial.row(0);
   |     --------------- ^
   |     |
   |     cannot assign to this expression
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [bnaecker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64865701/155423), if you want to implement it in a loop you could iterate along the axis using [`axis_iter_mut()`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.axis_iter_mut):

```rust
use ndarray::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut spec = array![
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8]
    ];
    
    let expo = array![2, 2, 2, 2];
    
    for mut row in spec.axis_iter_mut(Axis(0)) {
        row *= &expo;
    }
    
    println!("{}", spec);
}
```

```
[[2, 4, 6, 8],
 [10, 12, 14, 16]]
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution is approximately as fast as direct multiplication of all the rows at once. ~140ns for spec*expo vs
~140ns for 
 for mut row in spec.axis_iter_mut(Axis(0)) { row *= &expo; }
Note: Using the same array of the post examples.
Note2: I used criterion to measure performance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the first (pseudocode) loop you wrote is `for k in 0..m`, given that the size of your matrix is `m-by-n` and you want to apply this operation to each row.

If that's the case, then reading through the docs on [binary operations](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#arithmetic-operations) and [broadcasting](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#broadcasting), it looks like multiplying the arrays directly should be sufficient:

```rust
use ndarray::prelude::*; // 0.13.1

fn main() {
    // All rows in same time
    let spec = array![[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]; // mxn
    let exponencial = array![[2, 2, 2, 2]]; // matrix 1xn
    println!("{:?}", spec * exponencial);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8d63efefa37395863999decab1b2e89b)

You can see the output has each row doubled:

```
[[2, 4, 6, 8],
 [10, 12, 14, 16]], shape=[2, 4], strides=[4, 1], layout=C (0x1), const ndim=2
```

This works by *broadcasting*, which means operating as if the `1-by-n` array `exponencial` actually has shape `m-by-n`, by effectively replicating the array along the singleton dimension. This *awesome* trick was inspired by NumPy, which uses broadcasting heavily to compactly and efficiently express this kind of element-wise product.

Comment: *My intention is to **implement it in a loop** to compare with the implementation with other languages*

Comment: @Shepmaster Welp, I definitely missed _that_, thanks. Though I'm not sure why it must be a loop to do a cross-language comparison :)

Comment: Yeah, seems like you'd want to compare speed across languages using the "normal" mechanisms of each language. "Which is language is fastest when everyone can only go 1 km/hour" doesn't seem useful.

Comment: @Shepmaster Exactly, I'd expect the comparison to be between idiomatic implementations in each language. A for-loop in Rust and Python hardly seems fair!